# Unable to create Genymotion virtual devices:Connection timeout

Tags: connection, timeout, virtual, device, genymotion

I have successfully installed Genymotion and Virtualbox ,but not able to create virtual devices.
The error message as

**Unable to create Virtual Device:
Connection timeout.**

My network connection is ok.And the 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable**' cannot change installation path(it is installed in the path:E:),making the E disk a mass.

Comment: use freegate and set proxy in genymotion setting :127.0.0.1 port:8580

Answer (score 29):

Check the /home/user/.Genymobile/Genymotion/genymotion.log file and at last 10 lines of the file you will get somthing like this:

```
 Nov 7 06:39:54 [Genymotion] [Debug] Check that file is not already present 
    Nov 7 06:39:54 [Genymotion] [Debug] Getting currently authenticated user from  Hub 
    Nov 7 06:39:54 [Genymotion] [Debug] Network request to URL:  "/customer/me/" 
    Nov 7 06:39:56 [Genymotion] [Debug] Getting currently authenticated user from  local cache 
    Nov 7 06:39:56 [Genymotion] [Debug] Launching download 
 "/home/user/.Genymobile/Genymotion/ova/genymotion_vbox86t_4.1.1_130923_161308_w_gapps.ova" 
    Nov 7 06:39:57 [Genymotion] [Debug] Remote file size: 214548480 ,current local file size: 0 
    Nov 7 06:39:57 [Genymotion] [Debug] writting to local file with mode OpenMode( "WriteOnly" ) 
    Nov 7 06:39:57 [Genymotion] [Debug] Downloading file  "http://files2.genymotion.com/dists/4.1.1/ova/genymotion_vbox86t_4.1.1_130923_161308_w_gapps.ova" 
    Nov 7 06:39:57 [Genymotion] [Debug] Start timer 
    Nov 7 06:40:27 [Genymotion] [Debug] Timeout 
    Nov 7 06:40:27 [Genymotion] [Debug] Error code  2 :  ""
```

Then copy the link for the virtual device which is http://files2.genymotion.com/dists/4.1.1/ova/genymotion_vbox86t_4.1.1_130923_161308_w_gapps.ova and paste it on web browsers address bar and press enter. It will start downloading the image file. Then put this image file to /home/user/.Genymobile/Genymotion/ova/ and restart Genymotion.

Comment: The default path in Windows is C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Genymobile

Comment: That is a good idea but It didn't solve my problem. I think the problem   is related to internet connection.

Comment: This works for me. Note that after you have started the Genymotion, the device would still not be there. Click on "Add" then select again the device you wanted to create. Genymotion will now generate the device and you're ready to go.

Comment: How will the image file look like? I got something like JSON response

Answer (score 3):

Now, The genymobile file is change, In "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Genymobile".
In this file, you can find genymotion.log, open it, you can see the URL,copy it to your browser, you can download it.
note: if you are living in China, when you download the file in browser, you can set a vpn or proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem related with speed of your internet connection. Genymotion virtual device need good speed internet connection for loading before time out. Try one more time the downloadmanager of genymotion will resume from where you left so no worry keep trying you will get your problem solved :).

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
In some systems link is in this format:
https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/c6e1222c-993e-4bf2-840f-4795792f2143/getova

Copy link, sign in Genymotion website and Go to that address.
Then you can see download link in blow format:
http://files2.genymotion.com/dists/5.1.0/ova/genymotion_vbox86tp_5.1_150610_103034.ova

Download your device. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a mac and this worked for me:

1. Navigate to System Preferences >> Security & Privacy >> Firewall
2. Click on the lock to make changes, then click 'firewall options'
3. Add Genymotion the list of programs that 'Allow Incoming Connections'

Comment: perhaps rephrase the above as a set of steps for a user to take

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderton I did that

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 15.10 64bit:

1. Installed VirtualBox if you not
2. Download a *.ova which you need
3. Open it by VirtualBox and import it
4. Open Genymotion and you can see the android system which you need

Answer (score 0):

Keep trying.  It took me 4 tries, but I eventually started downloading the device.

Answer (score 0):

The connection gets timed out if you have a slow internet connection,

One solution if possible try to use higher internet speeds to download that

other solution is with existing connection, once the download gets stopped(timed out) once again download the same android device(which you downloaded previously) the download will resume from the previous state. So repeat this process till it gets downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way:go to add new device,select the device which timed out while downloading,and resume download.It will resume from where it stopped.It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Keying off of [HementKumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19826235/920564) I looked in the log to get the filename and then used wget with the continue flag (-c) to resume the download:

```
cd ~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/ova
wget -c http://files2.genymotion.com/dists/5.1.0/ova/genymotion_vbox86p_5.1_150609_195503.ova
```

Answer (score 0):

The downloading depends on ram of your device and your PC's "ram" which your downloading. Check the log file in i.e temperory files in geny motion and you will get to know the rest.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your hard disk space is full.

Try to import manually the `.ova` file in `VirtualBox`. There will be detailed error message.

The `.ova` file could be found here:

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\ova`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have completed the registration, including clicking the link in the verify email.  Then ensure that you are logged in on your application.  It also helped to get the latest version of Genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

I was have the same problem.
In my case the the problem was in proxy.
Our company use the TMG proxy. And, when i installed and setup the TMG Client, the issue was resolved!